# Entity Framework Code First - Invalid column ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a big ASP.NET MVC application database first and Entity Framework. It works fine with db first. I want to change application to Code first. And as a result I have error:

```
{"Invalid column name 'ID'"}
```

Also I have some inheritance classes.

All foreign keys mapped into OnModelCreating method and into classes as [ForeignKey("class name")] attribute

This is part of my code:

```
[Table("Member")]
public partial class Member
{
    public Member() {}

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Seed1")]
    public int? SeedID { get; set; }

    public virtual Seed Seed1 { get; set; }

    ...
}

[Table("Seed")]
public partial class Seed : Member
{
    public Seed()
    {
        Members = new HashSet<Member>();
    }

    public int Locale { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you have the model defined and the table structure?

Comment: How do you know the invalid column error originates from these classes. What is the code that generated the error?

Comment: If I rename column 'ID' to for example 'ID1' into Member class, I will get error "Invalid column 'ID1'" some times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
[Table("Member")]
public partial class Member
{
    public Member() {}

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public int? SeedID { get; set; }

    public virtual Seed Seed1 { get; set; }

    ...
}


[Table("Seed")]
public partial class Seed : Member
{
    public Seed()
    {
        Members = new HashSet<Member>();
    }

    public override int ID
    {
        get { return MemberID; }
        set { MemberID = value; }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public int MemberID { get; set; }

    public int Locale { get; set; }
}

public class SeedMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Seed>
{
    public SeedMap()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.ID);
        Property(c => c.ID)
            .HasColumnName("MemberID")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasMany(e => e.Members)
            .WithOptional(e => e.Seed1)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.SeedID);
    }
}
```